# Can my Early 2013 15" MacBook Pro connect to a 30" Apple Cinema Display... or two?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, cinema-display

Someone in my area is selling some 30" Apple Cinema Displays for a pretty decent price and I'm thinking about getting one for my home office to use with my Early 2013 15" MacBook Pro. From what I understand, I would need a Mini DisplayPort to Dual-Link DVI Adapter in order to get the display's native 2560x1440 resolution, but it looks like the seller is including one (whether or not they realize it didn't originally ship with the monitor).

**Bonus question:** if I picked up *two* of these (like I said, the price is pretty good), would my laptop be able to use them both at once? I have two Thunderbolt ports (assuming the seller throws in two adapters), but I don't know if there's an internal hardware or software limitation.

I'll certainly bring my laptop to test things out, but I figured I'd check before heading to meet the seller and potentially save myself a trip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, yes.

From https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.4-15-early-2013-retina-display-specs.html:

> This model supports a simultaneous maximum resolution up to 2560x1600 on two external displays via Thunderbolt. Alternately, it can support a single display up to 2560x1600 via Thunderbolt and a single display up to 1920x1200 via HDMI. Although it can theoretically power all three external displays, as confirmed by a helpful reader, it runs too hot with three displays connected.